# Текст о переносе ответа как дополнения в вопрос не переведён

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация, инструменты-модератора

Превратил ответ в дополнение к вопросу и увидел уведомление:

[image: скриншот]

При этом в [истории](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1063337/revisions) переведено корректно:

> ответ 1070261 добавлен как дополнение

Comment: Галочку поставь :P

Comment: Ладно, держи галку. Я ещё не переносил)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://ru.traducir.win/strings/13010

Добавил перевод:

> Ответ добавлен к вопросу как дополнение